# Is there a faster alternative to file.info()?

Tags: r, file

Is there a faster alternative to `file.info()` in R?  I am extracting the the file metadata for >200,000 18 mb '.wav' files. `file.info()` generally provides what I need in terms of information. However, running this on >200,000 files can take a very long time (hours). I have managed to bring it down to about 30 minutes by setting `file.info(x, extra_cols=F)`, but I am just wondering if there is a different function or set of functions that will operate faster. Alternatively, I am also interested in why this is so slow.

Comment: What info specifically are you after?

Comment: All of the info supplied by file.info.

Comment: You should try a shell command, which is likely to get the info you need faster. You may need to use, e.g., `read.table` to get the results into a data frame; see the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70165832/running-powershell-command-from-r-unexpected-token-in-expression-or-statement/70166975). There the OP is running R under Windows, but you can adapt the answer to Unix...