# Running powershell command from R: Unexpected token in expression or statement

Tags: r, powershell

I tried the following command (which works in powershell window)

```
system('powershell -command \"Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.html" | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge "11/12/2021 09:10:00" }\"')
```

However, from the R console I get the error:

```
At line:1 char:79
+ ... er *.html | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge 11/12/2021 09:10:00 }
+                                                                ~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '09:10:00' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
 
[1] 1
```

**EDIT**
Using Mikael Jagan's idea I managed to get a result:

```
system(paste('powershell -command ',shQuote('Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.html" | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge "11/30/2021 09:10:00" }')))
```

However, as you see below, the result is a character vector rather a dataframe. Is there a way to get only a vector with the filenames?

```
 [1] ""
 [2] ""
 [3] "    Directory: C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\R_Data\\texk"
 [4] ""
 [5] ""
 [6] "Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                 "
 [7] "----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                 "
 [8] "-a----        30/11/2021     10:31         386751 auth_cash_flow.html                                                  "
 [9] "-a----        30/11/2021     10:31         189370 auth_cash_flow_total.html                                            "
[10] "-a----        30/11/2021     10:31         552947 auth_symv_gantt.html                                                 "
[11] "-a----        30/11/2021     10:31          93238 auth_tender_schedule.html                                            "
[12] "-a----        30/11/2021     10:30         683088 dev_constr_pivot.html                                                "
[13] "-a----        30/11/2021     10:30          70224 form_org_chart.html                                                  "
[14] "-a----        30/11/2021     10:31         199907 form_org_chart2.html                                                 "
[15] "-a----        30/11/2021     10:30         618821 form_workload.html                                                   "
[16] "-a----        30/11/2021     10:30         109127 index.html                                                           "
[17] ""
[18] ""
```

This is my session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Greek_Greece.1253  LC_CTYPE=Greek_Greece.1253    LC_MONETARY=Greek_Greece.1253
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                  LC_TIME=Greek_Greece.1253    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.5 tools_4.0.5
```

Comment: @Mikael Jagan I still get the same error...

Comment: As an alternative, what is that command supposed to return? Maybe do it directly using R? See `file.info`.

Comment: Related info about the error: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25246735/680068 we need to use quotes around strings.

Comment: You may need to wrap the shell command in `shQuote`. There are Windows-specific examples in `?shQuote` that you should try, if only to see what works. (Deleting my initial comment, which contains a typo anyway, to avoid clutter.)

Comment: @zx8754 I want to get the names of a very small portion of the files in a directory (by date modified). I do not want to bring the complete list into R and then filter. `file.info`  does not allow me to pass a filter.

Comment: After getting info on all "html" files, we can filter the dataframe in R based on date, e.g.:  `x <- file.info(list.files(pattern = "*.html")); x[ as.Date(x$mtime) > as.Date("2021-11-01"), ]`

Comment: @Mikael Jagan Thanks, this one worked: `system(paste('powershell -command ',shQuote('Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.html" | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge "11/30/2021 09:10:00" }')))` . Now I face another problem: the result is not a dataframe and I can't get only the filenames easily...

Comment: @zx8754 No, I don't like that. The directory is huge, and I have to run the code very often.

Comment: @Brani I would suggest posting sample output, but regex is not really within the scope of this question.

Comment: @Brani Better to share text, not screenshot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x <- system(paste('powershell -command ',shQuote('Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.html" | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge "11/30/2021 09:10:00" } | Select -exp Name')), intern = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this? I am assuming from your sample output (a) that file names only occur at the end of a line of shell output followed by zero or more spaces and (b) that file names contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores prior to the `.html` suffix. If that is not the case, then the regular expressions in the second and third lines would need to be generalized slightly.

```r
## Get shell output as character vector
x <- system(paste('powershell -command', shQuote('Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.html" | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge "11/30/2021 09:10:00" } | Select -exp Name')), intern = TRUE)

## Find lines ending in ".html" followed by zero or more spaces
i <- grep("\\.html\\s*$", x)

## Extract file names from those lines
fn <- sub("^.* (\\w*\\.html)\\s*$", "\\1", x[i])
```

Here is a test with the lines from your shell output:

```r
x <- c(
  "",
  "",
  "    Directory: C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\R_Data\\texk",
  "",
  "",
  "Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                 ",
  "----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                 ",
  "-a----        30/11/2021     10:31         386751 auth_cash_flow.html                                                  ",
  "-a----        30/11/2021     10:31         189370 auth_cash_flow_total.html                                            ",
  "-a----        30/11/2021     10:31         552947 auth_symv_gantt.html                                                 ",
  "-a----        30/11/2021     10:31          93238 auth_tender_schedule.html                                            ",
  "-a----        30/11/2021     10:30         683088 dev_constr_pivot.html                                                ",
  "-a----        30/11/2021     10:30          70224 form_org_chart.html                                                  ",
  "-a----        30/11/2021     10:31         199907 form_org_chart2.html                                                 ",
  "-a----        30/11/2021     10:30         618821 form_workload.html                                                   ",
  "-a----        30/11/2021     10:30         109127 index.html                                                           ",
  "",
  ""
)

i <- grep("\\.html\\s*$", x)
i
# [1]  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16

fn <- sub("^.* (\\w*\\.html)\\s*$", "\\1", x[i])
fn
# [1] "auth_cash_flow.html"       "auth_cash_flow_total.html"
# [3] "auth_symv_gantt.html"      "auth_tender_schedule.html"
# [5] "dev_constr_pivot.html"     "form_org_chart.html"      
# [7] "form_org_chart2.html"      "form_workload.html"       
# [9] "index.html"
```

And in case you *do* want a data frame in the end:

```r
## Read lines of shell output containing file names into table
tc <- textConnection(x[i])
dd <- read.table(tc)
names(dd) <- c("mode", "date", "time", "length", "name")
close(tc)

## Coerce character date and time to useful date-time class
dd$time <- as.POSIXct(paste(dd$date, dd$time), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
dd$date <- NULL
dd
#     mode                time length                      name
# 1 -a---- 2021-11-30 10:31:00 386751       auth_cash_flow.html
# 2 -a---- 2021-11-30 10:31:00 189370 auth_cash_flow_total.html
# 3 -a---- 2021-11-30 10:31:00 552947      auth_symv_gantt.html
# 4 -a---- 2021-11-30 10:31:00  93238 auth_tender_schedule.html
# 5 -a---- 2021-11-30 10:30:00 683088     dev_constr_pivot.html
# 6 -a---- 2021-11-30 10:30:00  70224       form_org_chart.html
# 7 -a---- 2021-11-30 10:31:00 199907      form_org_chart2.html
# 8 -a---- 2021-11-30 10:30:00 618821        form_workload.html
# 9 -a---- 2021-11-30 10:30:00 109127                index.html
```

My opinion is that this is all quite a lot of work just to get around using `file.info`, which is designed specifically for this task. It may be worth doing a benchmark to determine whether the `file.info` approach is actually as slow as you think.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, this can done using *R*'s dedicated function *file.info()*, it is about 6x times faster than powershell answer provided by [GeorgeDontas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70166745/680068).

Benchmarking is done on a folder with 1228 files, of which 553 match on `"*.txt"`, then filter on date, gives 5 files:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  R = {
    files <- file.info(list.files(pattern = "*.txt"))
    rownames(files[ files$mtime > as.POSIXct("01/01/2021 09:10:00", format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"), ])
  },
  PS = {
    system(paste('powershell -command ',
                 shQuote('Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.txt" | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge "01/01/2021 09:10:00" } | Select -exp Name')), 
           intern = TRUE)
  })

# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median        uq       max neval
#     R 147.7614 161.6208 173.5587 168.8470  181.1235  261.7563   100
#    PS 801.9531 959.1979 997.8903 999.4841 1024.4515 1259.1713   100

# ~6x
# 997/168 = 5.934524
```

**Note:** I understand OP might have valid reasons to use *powershell* approach, posting this answer as a benchmark.

Comment: Thanks - `file.info` is definitely the canonical answer for most people thinking about how to do this...

Comment: Does the same apply to a directory of 300,000 files?

Comment: @GeorgeDontas I can't tell, I don't have such folder on my Windows machine at the moment, if someone has such folder, it would be nice to see the results.

Comment: I tried a folder of about 200,000 files. It took PS about 15 seconds. I am still waiting (several minutes) for the R alternative to finish (RGui is not responding).

Comment: @GeorgeDontas Thank you for testing, not surprised, I think your answer is the correct one when we have thousands of files. I will keep this answer as an alternative.

Comment: Have we discerned whether the bottleneck is `list.files` or `file.info` in this situation? If the latter, then I'll point out that `?file.info` suggests passing `extra_cols = FALSE` to speed things up. In any case, thanks for the testing the asymptotic case.

Comment: Wow @MikaelJagan is a game changer. Definitely use `extra_cols = FALSE`.